# Переписать SQL запрос в HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Необходимо переписать запрос

```
SELECT * FROM learn.employee
JOIN learn.department on department.id
WHERE department.head_id = employee.id and month(employee.hire_date) < 3;
```

в HQL. Делал так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Employee e INNER JOIN e.department d WHERE e.ledDepartment = d.headId AND e.hireDate < :month
```

Проблема в том, что не понимаю, как указать параметр месяца. Необходимо вывести руководителей отделов, которые вышли на работу до марта. Если в параметр вставлять обьект Date, то как сделать, чтобы был только Март месяц. Если указать целое число для month - Hibernate ругается, что невозможно сравнить Date и Integer.

Comment: А если заместь month указывать date вида 28.02.20.. или 01.03.20.. Ну собственно в формате Вашего hireDate.

Comment: SQL запрос возвращает руководителей отделов, которые устроились в организацию марта месяца (любого года). В этом и проблема. В sql я использовал функцию month() которая возвращала месяц из даты, я не знаю какую аналогичную функцию использовать в hql или может задать параметр даты (класс Date), но там же надо задать и год и число, а год всегда разный....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте фунцкию HQL - MONTH(...):

```
select so from SomeObject so where MONTH(so.date) = MONTH(:date)
```

либо:

```
select so from SomeObject so where TO_CHAR(so.date, 'MM') = :month_as_string
```

Comment: Сделал HQL-запрос: Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Employee e WHERE MONTH(e.hireDate) < MONTH(:month)");
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
        Date date=calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(date);
        query.setParameter("month", date); все получилось - спасибо!